# Nuevo estudio de plantilla CommandBar

Tags: uwp, app.xaml

How can I put the CommandBar on top of the Desktop and at the bottom on the mobile device?.`enter code here`
 `enter code here`

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="TitleRow" Height="48"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 `enter code here`   <TextBlock
        x:Name="TitlePage"
        x:Uid="Main_Title"
         FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeMedium}" Foreground="{StaticResource RedBrush}" FontWeight="SemiLight" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="0,0,12,7"/>

 `enter code here`   <CommandBar x:Name="Topbar" Margin="0,0,12,7"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed"  >
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton  x:Name="AddButton" Icon="Accept" x:Uid="Aceptar"  Foreground="{StaticResource RedBrush}" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are asking? With current writing, it's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: On desktop I have the CommandBar at the top when I throw the emulator the CommandBar is still up, I want it with the visualstate, when this in DESKOTP this in the top, when this a smartphone is at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using VisualStates, you can have three rows in your Grid and just change the `CommandBar`'s `Grid.Row` value with an `AdaptiveTrigger` using the Width of the app.

[Here is a video of the example code below at run-time](https://www.screencast.com/t/DI61MC9dT).

UPDATE

To re-iterate what I stated in my last comment, you no longer need to use "Page.AppBar" property. In fact, you don't want to use it because your Grid's `VisualStateManager` can't alter page level properties.

Instead you can do what I show below (it's a complete, working, example):

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea"
          Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CommandBar x:Name="MyAppBar"
                    Grid.Row="0" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkGray">
            <TextBlock Text="This is where your page content would go" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--  Adaptive triggers  -->
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="640" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MyAppBar.(Grid.Row)"
                                Value="0" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MyAppBar.(Grid.Row)"
                                Value="2" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
```

When the app is on mobile, the screen will be less than 640epx wide and the CommandBar will at the bottom. Otherwise, it will be on the top.

Comment: Problem is that I stay up in the Samrtphone part, will not have to use <Page.TopAppBar> </Page.TopAppBar> and also <Page.BottompAppBar> </Page.BottompAppBar>. After with the Visualsate

Comment: I'm using template studio

Comment: Template Studio just generates XAML. You can customize it after the fact. In the case where you have two commandBar properties (Top & Bottom), then just create both of them and toggle each the CommandBar.Visibility property depending on the VisualState

Comment: As I can place the lower command in the XAML, sgun the code that is put up

Comment: For what you're trying to do, you wouldn't want to use Page.TopAppBar and Page.BottomAppBar because the VisualStateManager can't set the properties. Instead, you can go with the approach I mentioned so you have more flexibility. I've updated my answer to provide all the code from a working demo I just tested.

Comment: Thank you very much